# Resources in Windows Form

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, resx

I am trying to replicate one coding example in Visual Studio and I see that in a form there are some resx files.

[image: form to replicate]

I am trying to put a resx file into my form as well so I created a new resource file but as I try to  move it on the form in solution explorer i get an error saying i cannot do that (`"destination folder is the same as the origin"`)

[image: "destination folder is the same as the origin"]

I am new to Visual Basic so maybe I am missing something but where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at [ASK]. Currently it's unclear what you are trying to do. Please add more description, screenshots and code if required and let us know what the problem you have faced with.

Comment: It is just not the proper procedure to create a form's .resx file.  Whatever you try to do next is likely to fail with an inscrutable error message.  The designer creates it as necessary to store the resources used by controls on the form.  Or to localize the app, presumably the real intention.  Set the form's Language property to add a language-specific .resx file.  Google "windows forms how to localize a form" to learn more about it.

Answer (score -1):

Rename the copy of folder and files because two folders with same name can not exist at same place.

Copy file to outside anyway rename and again paste there.